# PowerShell Passing PSCUSTOM object to json

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, automation

I think this is something to do with it going through azure automation...

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$tBody = @{
    'caller'=$caller # this is just a string 'something@something.com'
    'pscustomobject' = $pscustomobject # this is a pscustom object
    }        
$passToAction = [pscustomobject]@{
    paramblock = $paramBlock # this is a pscustom object and one of the objects is another pscustomobject called pscustomobject which is a pscustomobject that was convertto-csv -notypeinformation converted
}
$passToActionJSON = $passToAction| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
```

Long story short on the other side .... I do as much converfrom-json as I can.  But I end up with a string that looks like this:

```
$b.paramblock.pscustomobject
@{TimeGenerated=2020-12-22T23:22:17.527Z; protocol=Kerberos; AuthServer=stuff; IpAddress=suff; NonExistentUser=stuff; TargetDomainName=
stuff; vmName=stuff}
@{TimeGenerated=2020-12-22T23:22:17.527Z; protocol=Kerberos; AuthServer=stuff; IpAddress=suff; NonExistentUser=stuff; TargetDomainName=
stuff; vmName=stuff}
@{TimeGenerated=2020-12-22T23:22:17.527Z; protocol=Kerberos; AuthServer=stuff; IpAddress=suff; NonExistentUser=stuff; TargetDomainName=
stuff; vmName=stuff}
```

Anyone have a idea how to turn this back into something usable?  What I really want is it back into a pscustomobject.  If you have a better method to send it great, but im working in azure automation so no promise to any .net class being there.

Comment: Pretty confusing... What is `$b`? Where does `$tbody` go to?. Try to build a [mcve] in your question. See also: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Anyways to get an idea how your PowerShell expression should look like to build your specific json string, try this `$Object = ConvertFrom-Json $Json` (`-AsHashTable`) and than [`ConvertTo-Expression $Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression)

Comment: Without showing where all the undefined variables come from and what they are supposed to contain, I very much doubt anyone will be able to give you an answer to this..

Comment: (Agree with comments above) .. What is `$caller` variable type and value?  What is `$pscustomobject` variable type and value?  What is `$paramBlock` variable type and value?  Your 'other side' looks like an array of [PSCustomObject], but your example shows no use of `TimeGenerated`, `protocol`, `AuthServer`, `IpAddress`, or `vmName` property assignments or declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the workflow I had

```
-> $pscustomobject =
--> something = something
--> something2 = ($pscustomobject | convertto-json)
--> something3 = something3

-> $newpscustomobject =
--> paramblock = $pscustomobject

-> $newpscustomobject | convertto-json -depth 99
```

this turned it into plain junk

long story short keep each pscustomobject to two levels else powershell jackes it up

```
        $paramBlock = @()
        $paramBlock = [pscustomobject]@{
            ticket_body = $ticket_body
            ticket_short_description = $subject
            category = 'stuff'
            subcategory = 'Other'
            assignment_group = 'stuff'
            csvname = 'stuff.csv'
            location = 'waco'
        }
        $passToAction = [pscustomobject]@{
            paramblock = $paramBlock # pscustomobject
            csvattachment = $eventsQueryResults #pscustomobject
        }
        $passToActionJson = $passToAction | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
        Invoke-AutomationWatcherAction -Message $subject -Data $passToActionJson
```